# How could I align the label and select box

Tags: css, responsive-design

I included [this theme](http://egemem.com/theme/kode/v1.1/) in my website

and It seems  `label` and `select dropdown` can not be aligned well.

How could I fix the the layout broken problem ?

here's the live demo http://lazyair.co/user/index

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove margin-top from:

```css
/* line 5, /home/poc/lazy-bird-website/app/assets/stylesheets/city.scss */
#nav-btn-monthly, .btn, .btn-large, .btn-flat {
  padding: 0 0.1rem;
  width: 90px;
  /* margin-top: 20px; */
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.0rem;
}
```

Comment: you helped my find out the root cause, thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Remove the 20px top margin from the drop-down:

```
.btn.selectpicker{
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" title="高雄" aria-expanded="false"><span class="filter-option pull-left">高雄</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
```

you can remove the top margin from this button for this select field only.